# What are the consequences of filing personal income tax return past the deadline of April 15th (i.e. filing late)? [US]

Tags: united-states, income-tax

Today – April 15th – is the income tax filing deadline in the U.S.

Here in Canada, we still have until the end of the month.  Perhaps we get a little longer to figure things out because we pay more tax than our American friends?  ;-)

Anyway, I'm curious about **late tax filing in the U.S.**, and I'm sure a few others are too!

So, here are my questions about not filing a personal income tax return on time:

- If you don't owe money, do you need to file on time?  Do you even need to file at all?
- If you **do** owe money and don't file on time, what are the penalties?
- Are some individuals specifically permitted to file late?  If so, why?
- Is there a way to ask the IRS for an extension for special circumstances?
- Are there any other consequences to filing late?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. You do need to file if you want your refund.  The IRS has a [questionnaire](http://www.irs.gov/individuals/article/0,,id=96623,00.html) to determine whether you need to file at all.  (See the answer to question 4 about filing on time.)
2. There is a failure to file penalty of 5% of the tax due per month or part of month the return is late, up to 25%.  There is a failure to pay penalty of 0.5% of the tax due per month or part of month the return is late, and this can go up without limit.  Interest accrues on the unpaid tax as well.  ([Source](http://taxes.about.com/od/backtaxes/qt/irs_tax_penalty.htm))
3. Some individuals [can file late](http://www.irs.gov/formspubs/article/0,,id=98155,00.html), including those in active combat zones.
4. No special circumstances necessary!  [Form 4868](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f4868.pdf) gives you an extra six months to file.  (This is not an extra six months to *pay*, though!)  Just get the form in by the regular due date and it's good to go.
5. It weighs mercilessly on your psyche.  Also, if you're due a refund, the government holds onto it (interest-free, of course!) until you get the stupid things in.

Comment: I am astonished this Q/A pairing doesn't have more views and votes